# jQuery best way to traverse the HTML and add tooltip - dynamically

Tags: jquery, html

I'm having the below code(Unordered list inside a Div)

```
<div id="sample">
    <ul class="choice">
        <li class="test">
<span>12.2 - Some Text 123</span>

        </li>
        <li class="test">
<span>QWW.22.333 - Some Text 23</span>

        </li>
        <li class="test">
<span>Qd - Some Text 12</span>

        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Trying to achieve 2 things with jQuery.

- First I need to remove the text("-  Some text...") inside all the `span`
- second I need to set the removed text in earlier step as `title` for `span` without Hyphen in the front.

and my final output will be like this

```
<div id="sample">
    <ul class="choice">
        <li class="test"> <span title="Some Text 123">12.2</span>

        </li>
        <li class="test"> <span title="Some Text 23">QWW.22.333</span>

        </li>
        <li class="test"> <span title="Some Text 12">Qd</span>

        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

What is the best way I can do this using jQuery ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Get the list of `span`'s in that `div`.
2. Iterate each `span` and split its text with using **`.split()`**  based on `-` so you can set title and text.

---

```
var lsSpans = $('#sample').find('span'); //returns the list of spans within it
$.each(lsSpans, function (i, j) {
   var txt = $(this).text().split('-'); //split the text in span
   $(this).attr('title', txt[1]);       //Set title attribute
   $(this).text(txt[0]);                //replace the text with float number
});
```

### [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/qD89S/)